# How to retrieve a mongo collection matching the array items in any order?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following mongo document stored on `stocks` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d14eb6e7a99c30956b842e1"),
    "propertiesValues" : [
        {
            "property_id" : "5c5460604bb12b02277f26d5",
            "value" : "SEMI FOSCO"
        },
        {
            "property_id" : "5c38bb491cddf30213c2fb13",
            "value" : "LL"
        },
        {
            "property_id" : "5ba9304f13a60b02f1b5d2c1",
            "value" : "GARGOYLE"
        },
        {
            "property_id" : "5c38bbf01cddf30213c2fb17",
            "value" : "7/8 pes"
        },
        {
            "property_id" : "5c545ecd4bb12b02277f26ca",
            "value" : "VESTUÁRIO"
        }
    ],
    "materialDefinition_id" : ObjectId("5b68b9d1a4e46302c325e01e"),
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "createdAt" : 1561652078846,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Why is the given query returning no fields:

```
db.stocks.find({ propertiesValues: [ { property_id: '5ba9304f13a60b02f1b5d2c1', value: 'GARGOYLE' }, { property_id: '5c38bb491cddf30213c2fb13', value: 'LL' }, { property_id: '5c38bbf01cddf30213c2fb17', value: '7/8 pes' }, { property_id: '5c545ecd4bb12b02277f26ca', value: 'VESTUÁRIO' }, { property_id: '5c5460604bb12b02277f26d5', value: 'SEMI FOSCO' } ] },{}).pretty();
```

I was expecting to retrieve the given document with the given query, but it is retuning no data.

How to properly fix that (the `propertiesValue` may occur in any order, so the solution must be able to return the exact items on any order they are stored)

EDIT

The following query returns the requested data:

```
db.stocks.find({ propertiesValues: [ { property_id: '5c5460604bb12b02277f26d5', value: 'SEMI FOSCO' }, { property_id: '5c38bb491cddf30213c2fb13', value: 'LL' },  { property_id: '5ba9304f13a60b02f1b5d2c1', value: 'GARGOYLE' },  { property_id: '5c38bbf01cddf30213c2fb17', value: '7/8 pes' },  { property_id: '5c545ecd4bb12b02277f26ca', value: 'VESTUÁRIO' }] },{}).pretty();
```

The difference is that this lask query is in the exact order of the document.

This does not work for me as I cannot guarantee the order of the query parameters, so I need a solution that adhere to the following conditions:

**VALID RETURN**

- If there are ALL of the required `propertiesValues` in the, return the data
- If there are ALL of the required `propertiesValues` in a different order, return the data

**INVALID RETURN**

- If there are MORE or LESS elements in the `propertiesValues`, does not return the data
- If any element content (`property_id` or `value`) is different, does not return the data

In other word, I need a exact match of `property_id` and `value` fields no matter on what order they occur.

Comment: is there a chance you are just using the wrong collection? you stated its on orders but the query shows you use stocks

Comment: Typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the collection you have specified while describing the document and the collection on which you are querying are different.

Moving forward, you can use $all operator for your query.

```
db.collection.find({ propertiesValues: { "$all": [ { property_id: '5ba9304f13a60b02f1b5d2c1', value: 'GARGOYLE' }, { property_id: '5c38bb491cddf30213c2fb13', value: 'LL' }, { property_id: '5c38bbf01cddf30213c2fb17', value: '7/8 pes' }, { property_id: '5c545ecd4bb12b02277f26ca', value: 'VESTUÁRIO' }, { property_id: '5c5460604bb12b02277f26d5', value: 'SEMI FOSCO' } ] }}).pretty();
```

It will match the documents in any order.

MongoDB Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with $all like this:

```
{ "propertiesValues": { "$size" : 5, "$all": [ { property_id: '5ba9304f13a60b02f1b5d2c1', value: 'GARGOYLE' }, { property_id: '5c38bb491cddf30213c2fb13', value: 'LL' }, { property_id: '5c38bbf01cddf30213c2fb17', value: '7/8 pes' }, { property_id: '5c545ecd4bb12b02277f26ca', value: 'VESTUÁRIO' }, { property_id: '5c5460604bb12b02277f26d5', value: 'SEMI FOSCO' } ]  }}
```

Adding the $size check guarantees exact match.